# HTML5: Canvas circle is oval because of width and height

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, height, width

```
var qcanvas = $('#canvas');
var canvas = ctl_canvas[0];
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
qcanvas.css('border', '1px solid black');
qcanvas.css('width', 400);
qcanvas.css('height', 75);
```

When I use the above `qcanvas.css('width', 400);` and respective height css, the **actual** height of the canvas is not what I set it to using the jquery functions. Does anyone know how I can not use `canvas.width = 400;` and use the propery jquery functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.width` and `.height` properties of a canvas are independent of the CSS properties of the same name.

The CSS properties set the visible size, but the element properties set the coordinate space.

You *should* set the width and height properties directly:

```
qcanvas.width = 400;
qcanvas.height = 75;
```

Ideally set the CSS properties to the same, which is the default in any event unless specifically changed.

This ensures that your coordinate systems are consistent.  If they're not the same then the browser will apply scaling to map from one coordinate system to the other, and you would also have to apply your own scaling to map event coordinates to pixel coordinates.

Comment: Setting both properties solved my problems, and on my previous issues as well! :)

Comment: @BrianGraham it's normally safe to leave the CSS properties unset.

Answer (score 0):

```
qcanvas.css('width', '400px');
qcanvas.css('height', '75px');
```

You need to specify `px`.

Comment: Another way would be `qcanvas.width(400).height(75)`.